# Jolt Transformation Spec with array values

Tags: jolt

Using the below input trying to generate the desired output, condition based in the array of values is not working. can you provide some inputs on this.
Based on customer and promotion type need to append the amount values

```json
{
  "Id": "100",
  "name": "Test",
  "discounts": [
    {
      "TypeCode": "customer",
      "Amount": 20
      },
    {
      "TypeCode": "promotion",
      "Amount": 10
    }
   ],
   "items": [
    {
      "LineId": "1001",
      "lineItem": "TestProduct",
      "discountDetails": [
        {
          "LineTypeCode": "customer",
          "discountAmount": 300
        },
        {
          "LineTypeCode": "customer",
           "discountAmount": 330
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output format :

```json
{
  "Id": "100",
  "name": "Test",
  customerAmount : 20,
  promotionAmount : 10,
  "items": [
    {
      "LineId": "1001",
      "lineItem": "TestProduct",
      "customerlineamount" : 300,
      "foclineamount" : 330
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional logic is needed in order to extract the third and fourth elements with `Amount` keys such as

```json
"discounts": {
    "*": {
        "TypeCode": {
            "customer": {
                "@(2,Amount)": "customerAmount"
            },
            "promotion": {
                "@(2,Amount)": "promotionAmount"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and define `items` array through prepending `items.[&1]` for each key, which should be in the result set, in order to go one level up. So, use the following complete specification of Jolt such as

```json
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "Id": "Id",
    "name": "name",
    "discounts": {
      "*": {
        "TypeCode": {
          "customer": {
            "@(2,Amount)": "customerAmount"
          },
          "promotion": {
            "@(2,Amount)": "promotionAmount"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "items": {
      "*": {
        "LineId": "items.[&1].LineId",
        "lineItem": "items.[&1].lineItem",
        "@(2,items[0].discountDetails[0].discountAmount)": "items.[&1].customerlineamount",
        "@(2,items[0].discountDetails[1].discountAmount)": "items.[&1].foclineamount"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```